# Need help dual-booting ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, windows-8

I have a laptop with Windows 8 installed on it, it is the HP 2000 series. got it for Christmas in 2012. I inserted a CD with Ubuntu 12.10 in it (I got the CD before ubuntu 13.04 came out) and it was confirmed on another PC it worked, right now I'm downloading 13.04. and when I inserted the CD into this laptop, it didn't boot into Ubuntu, it went to Windows 8...

Comment: Could you add what you have tried and add any evidence of research as well as better describing what you need help with.  Adding a link for your motherboard manual from manufacturers website may provide the info for any body to give help on how to boot your laptop from DVD if this is what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 comes with a technology called "Secure Boot", which runs on top of UEFI and prevents a user from manually booting to another device. To get around it, you must:

1. When inside Windows 8, go to the charms menu by pressing [Windows key] and [C].
2. Select power symbol at the bottom of the menu.
3. While holding the [Shift] key, click "Restart".
4. When your computer reboots, choose the "Use a device" option, and your live CD should be available as an option there.

Helpful links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Comment: I click the device charm, all I see is Second Screen. I have no disc in the drive & I'm not running Developer, Consumer, or Release Preview. There's also nothing in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the screen right as your laptop boots up. You're going to hit one of the F# keys to get into the boot menu (mine is F12).

When you're in the boot menu, you need to tell the laptop to boot from the CD, and that should get you to the Ubuntu LiveCD where you can install or simply try out the OS.

*Note: If there isn't a 'quick boot menu' or something similar, and you only see Setup (usually F2 or F4), you can still change your boot order from there. Just go into Setup/BIOS and look around to find the settings on boot order. Don't forget to change it back later if your bios doesn't have quick boot.*

Comment: When I boot my laptop, there seems to be no splash screen, just first a black screen then the HP logo shows in place of the Windows 8 logo with the spinning wheel, is that normal? and how do I tell the laptop to get into the boot menu?

Comment: Apologies, it seems HP uses uncommon keys for their boot menu and bios. To get into the boot menu, hit Escape as it starts. Do this right as it boots up. Personally I'd tap it two or three times to make sure it goes through. If you cannot get into boot menu, tapping Delete multiple times will get you into the BIOS.